# ¿Como validar estos dos campos en Laravel con "Auth"?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

estoy intentando hacer un login desde una BD Oracle externa , ya mi proyecto laravel se conecta a esta y los modelos sirven perfectamente para hacer consultas, pero cuando intento usar el **Auth::attempt()** con las credenciales del formulario, siempre me dice que es invalido el usuario cuando es válido.

La situación es la siguiente, tengo dos campos, el campo "**LOGUSE**" y el campo "**PASUSE**", son campos que no se pueden cambiar, de poder lo hubiera hecho, esa es la primera complicación ya que tengo entendido que laravel autentica por defecto el campo "**password**" y no se puede cambiar, a menos que en el modelo coloquemos en el metodo "**getAuthPassword()**" que retorne el campo password.
**MODELO** Usuario.php:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{ 
    return $this->pasuse;
}
```

Ya lo hice, y ademas la contraseña del usuario está encriptada con **MD5**, cosa que el Auth de laravel no lo autentica si no es con **bcrypt()**. El campo username **tiene 15 espacios y en Mayúsculas** `"SYSTEM         "` -> es el usuario, acomodé en el Provider de OracleUserProvider que trae yajra/laravel-oci-8, le agregué el metodo **validateCredentials()** con lo siguiente:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
    $hashed_value = $user->getAuthPassword();
    return $hashed_value == strtoupper(md5($plain));
}
```

**LoginController:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $email = str_pad($email, 15);
    $password = strtoupper($password);

    $credentials = ['loguse' => $email, 'password' => $password];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return "Usuario validado exitosamente";
    }
    else
    {
        return "No se validó el usuario";
    }
}
```

**Config/Auth.php -> Default:**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'custom',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

**Config/Auth.php -> Guards:**

```
'guards' => [
    'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'oracle_validate',
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'usuarios',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**Config/Auth.php -> Providers:**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'oracle_validate' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Usuario::class,
        'table' => 'usuarios',
    ],

],
```

**AuthServiceProvider:**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('oracle_validate', function ($app, array $config) {
        $model = $app['config']['auth.providers.users.model'];
        return new OracleUserProvider($app['hash'], $model);
    });
}
```

**Imagenes del Usuario:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probaste crear una funcion y pasar los method validate y luego llamarlo desde el method donde inicia el auth??

Comment: Disculpa amigo, pudieras ser mas específico...?, de todas maneras para que tengas una idea, me guié de este post: https://styde.net/crear-login-personalizado-en-laravel/

Comment: Cuando unas una tabla con estructura diferente necesitas otro Model que extienda Authenticatable

Comment: Tambien lo hice bro, solo que no mostré el model Usuario completo...